# Behavior when two superclasses has the same method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Out of pure curiosity I did the following.

```
class A:
    def x():
        print("A.x")

class B:
    def x():
        print("B.x")

class C(A,B):
    pass

C.x()
```

Which outputs

```
A.x
```

Now the behavior I expected was the later superclass's method `B.x` executing. Because I thought that methods for `A` will be defined first than methods of `B` will override them. Instead, `A.x` was printed. In fact the first superclass's method `.x` was always called. The same behavior was shown with instance methods.

Can anyone explain the way this is happening please?

Comment: It's called method resolution order. Google for `class.__mro__`. Basically the order of resolution is in the class attribute `__mro__` (So, `A.__mro__` and so on)

Comment: Try `print(C.__mro__)` to print the method resolution order.

Comment: On a side note, you want `@classmethod` decorating those methods.

Comment: And while figuring out the MRO of a class heirarchy with multiple inheritance is non-trivial, for a definition like: `class C(A,B)` in the MRO, it will always be `[C, A, B, ..., object]`